# How to get the children div in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, slider, switch-statement

I have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tid = 0;
  $c = 0;
  $immagine = $(".lazy"); //salvo la picuture visualizzata
  $rect = $(".active"); //salvo il rettangolo attivo
  $rect_first = $(".active");

  function loop() {
    $rect.next().attr("class", "active");
    $rect.attr("class", "");
    $rect = $rect.next();

    $immagine.next().attr("style", "vivibility: visible;");
    $immagine.attr("style", "visibility: hidden;");
    $immagine = $immagine.next();

    $c++;
    if ($c > 7) {
      goFirst();
    }
    tid = setTimeout(loop, 1500);
  }

  function goFirst() {
    $rect.attr("class", "");
    $rect_first.attr("class", "active");
    $rect = $rect_first;

    $immagine.attr("style", "visibility: hidden;");
    $immagine = $(".lazy");
    $immagine.attr("style", "visibility: visible;");
    $c = 0;
  }

  function handleMouseOver() {
    tid = setTimeout(loop, 1500);
  }

  $("span.miniatura")
    .one("mouseover", handleMouseOver) //questa funzione è chiamata una volta sola
    .on("mouseleave", function() { //questa può essere chiamata più volte
      clearTimeout(tid);
      $(this).one("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
      goFirst();
    });
})
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'vinegar_strokeregular';
  src: url('vinegar_stroke-webfont.eot');
  src: url('vinegar_stroke-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('vinegar_stroke-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('vinegar_stroke-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('vinegar_stroke-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('vinegar_stroke-webfont.svg#vinegar_strokeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/*POPUP CONTATTACI*/

#thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pop_background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
#pop_box {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 4px solid #f4850f;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  z-index: 1500;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#pop_box form {
  padding-top: 3%;
}
#pop_box form label {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 1%;
}
#pop_box textarea {
  width: 60%;
  resize: none;
}
#pop_box input {
  width: 40%;
}
#pop_box #mex {
  margin-left: -4.5%;
}
#close_button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
}
/*FINE POPOUP*/

aside {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 19%;
  border: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: ridge;
}
#ricerca {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.srcbar {
  height: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  outline: none;
}
#buttonsearch {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #F6A957;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#s {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #333;
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: #414141;
}
#login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #414141;
}
#login a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: verdana;
  color: grey;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
#login a:hover {
  color: #F6A957;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#login img {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#logo {
  height: 80px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
#top {
  background-image: url(http://bicicletteria.altervista.org/image/Immagine_4.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
#topmenu li {
  display: inline;
}
#topmenu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
#topmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #414141;
  text-align: center;
}
#topmenu li a:hover {
  color: #F6A957;
  background-color: #111;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Eor57Ae.jpg);
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#container {
  display: block;
  width: 62%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  margin-left: 19%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#novita h1,
#piu_venduti h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "vinegar_strokeregular";
}
#container header {
  text-align: center;
}
#novita .products {
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 35%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#piu_venduti article {
  display: inline-block;
}
/*SLIDER IMMAGINI*/

#miniatura {
  position: relative;
}
#min {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}
#min img {
  border: 1px solid #646464;
}
ul.vid-rotater li {
  color: white;
}
.frame {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 7px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.frame img {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.pic {
  clear: both;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
}
.pic .frame {
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.pic img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 95%;
  left: 2.5%;
  right: 2.5%;
}
.pic:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vid-rotater {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  padding: 7px 5px 5px;
  left: 0px;
}
#min ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.vid-rotater li,
.vid-rotater a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 29px;
}
.vid-rotater li {
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
}
.vid-rotater a {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px 0 3px;
}
.vid-rotater span {
  background: #FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  line-height: 999em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.vid-rotater .active span {
  background: #F6A957 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-color: #660033;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*BOX PRODOTTI*/

.products {
  background-color: RGBa(65, 65, 65, 0.4);
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  margin-left: 2.25%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px groove #999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #BBB;
}
.descrizione {
  padding-top: 65%;
}
.products .miniatura {
  position: relative;
  left: 2.5%;
  right: 2.5%;
  width: 90%;
}
.products p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
footer {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-image: url(http://bicicletteria.altervista.org/image/Immagine_4.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #242424;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
footer dl,
dd {
  color: #F6A957;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*CHI SIAMO*/

#who h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "vinegar_strokeregular";
}
#who {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
}
#iframe {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 350px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}
#contattaci {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 48%;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 2%;
}
#contattaci a {
  display: inline;
}
#email {
  display: inline;
}
#who p {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 2%;
}
/*LOGIN*/

.login-block {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 4px solid #F6A957;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}
.login-block h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.login-block input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  outline: none;
}
.login-block input#username {
  background: #fff url('http://i.imgur.com/u0XmBmv.png') 20px top no-repeat;
  background-size: 16px 80px;
}
.login-block input#username:focus {
  background: #fff url('http://i.imgur.com/u0XmBmv.png') 20px bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 16px 80px;
}
.login-block input#password {
  background: #fff url('http://i.imgur.com/Qf83FTt.png') 20px top no-repeat;
  background-size: 16px 80px;
}
.login-block input#password:focus {
  background: #fff url('http://i.imgur.com/Qf83FTt.png') 20px bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 16px 80px;
}
.login-block input:active,
.login-block input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #F6A957;
}
.login-block button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #F6A957;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#send {
  width: 40%;
  background: #F6A957;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#add {
  width: 40%;
  /*min-width: 90px;*/
  background: #F6A957;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.login-block button:hover,
#send:hover,
#add:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #999;
}
/*PAGINA PRODOTTO*/

#up {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#down {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#sinistra {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
}
#sinistra img {
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 20%;
}
#centro {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
#centro img {
  width: 98%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
#destra {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
#dimensione {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 50px;
}
#qnt {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 25px;
}
/*MODIFICA QUANTITA*/

.quantity .oper {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.choose_quantity {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.quantity input {
  width: 45px;
  height: 18px;
  border: solid 1px #b8b8b8;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 3px 0;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
  font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="novita">
    <header>
      <h1>NOVITA'</h1>
    </header>
    <article class="products">
      <span class="miniatura">
                <span id="min" class="pic">
                  <ul class="vid-rotater" style="visibility: visible;">
                         <li class="active"><span>0</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>5</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>6</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>7</span>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="frame" href="http://www.cycling.it/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img class="lazy" src="http://www.cycling.it/foto_gallery/big/01-revelator_prestige_Di2_7805.jpg" data-original="" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9ty91M-QHPrgy6woAJAgdF68UrTD8c91WXz5dfznU1R_2GQ5Qjw" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.loriscycles.com/docs/gallery/2/bici_sx_101.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bici-da-corsa-da-donna-stella-wilier.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.wildpigs.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/status.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.milkywayshop.it/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/i/bici-fixed-margot-cycling-margot-dragonfly-12165.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
      </a>
      </span>
      </span>
      <section class="descrizione">
        <p class="modello">bici mfha536
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="marca">KTM
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="prezzo">3000.00 €
          <br>
        </p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section id="piu_venduti">
    <header>
      <h1>I PIU' VENDUTI</h1>
    </header>
    <article class="products">
      <span class="miniatura">
                <span id="min" class="pic">
                  <ul class="vid-rotater" style="visibility: visible;">
                         <li class="active"><span>0</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>5</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>6</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>7</span>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="frame" href="http://www.cycling.it/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img class="lazy" src="http://www.cycling.it/foto_gallery/big/01-revelator_prestige_Di2_7805.jpg" data-original="" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9ty91M-QHPrgy6woAJAgdF68UrTD8c91WXz5dfznU1R_2GQ5Qjw" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.loriscycles.com/docs/gallery/2/bici_sx_101.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bici-da-corsa-da-donna-stella-wilier.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.wildpigs.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/status.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.milkywayshop.it/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/i/bici-fixed-margot-cycling-margot-dragonfly-12165.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
      </a>
      </span>
      </span>
      <section class="descrizione">
        <p class="modello">bici mfha536
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="marca">KTM
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="prezzo">3000.00 €
          <br>
        </p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <!--secondo protodototo più venduto-->
    <article class="products">
      <span class="miniatura">
                  <span id="min" class="pic">
                    <ul class="vid-rotater" style="visibility: visible;">
                           <li class="active"><span>0</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>5</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>6</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>7</span>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="frame" href="http://www.cycling.it/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img class="lazy" src="http://www.cycling.it/foto_gallery/big/01-revelator_prestige_Di2_7805.jpg" data-original="" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9ty91M-QHPrgy6woAJAgdF68UrTD8c91WXz5dfznU1R_2GQ5Qjw" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.loriscycles.com/docs/gallery/2/bici_sx_101.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bici-da-corsa-da-donna-stella-wilier.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.wildpigs.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/status.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.milkywayshop.it/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/i/bici-fixed-margot-cycling-margot-dragonfly-12165.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
      </a>
      </span>
      </span>
      <section class="descrizione">
        <p class="modello">bici mfha536
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="marca">KTM
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="prezzo">3000.00 €
          <br>
        </p>
      </section>
    </article>
    <!--terzo protodototo più venduto-->
    <article class="products">
      <span class="miniatura">
                    <span id="min" class="pic">
                      <ul class="vid-rotater" style="visibility: visible;">
                             <li class="active"><span>0</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>5</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>6</span>
      </li>
      <li class=""><span>7</span>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="frame" href="http://www.cycling.it/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img class="lazy" src="http://www.cycling.it/foto_gallery/big/01-revelator_prestige_Di2_7805.jpg" data-original="" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9ty91M-QHPrgy6woAJAgdF68UrTD8c91WXz5dfznU1R_2GQ5Qjw" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.loriscycles.com/docs/gallery/2/bici_sx_101.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bici-da-corsa-da-donna-stella-wilier.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.wildpigs.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/status.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="http://www.milkywayshop.it/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/i/bici-fixed-margot-cycling-margot-dragonfly-12165.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
      </a>
      </span>
      </span>
      <section class="descrizione">
        <p class="modello">bici mfha536
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="marca">KTM
          <br>
        </p>
        <p class="prezzo">3000.00 €
          <br>
        </p>
      </section>
    </article>

  </section>
</div>
```

Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kwnwj6q/)

I want to change the image of `img` where I have the mouseover, but with my jQuery code I change the image of all `img` in my page. Where is the error?
Thanks guys!

Comment: Please put your code in the question itself - Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

Comment: Where's the code? We shouldn't have to go off site to be able to review your full question. Questions should be self contained. There is  reason you were wrned that you can't provide a link to a fiddle without including code

Comment: You should have a closer look on your functions. As a hint `$(this)` insine an event-handler contains the element which has triggered the event.
P.S.: Did you tried to move over the list-items multiple times? This will create a loop everytime and the images will variyng wildly.

Comment: sorry, but i'm a new in this forum, the problem is that when i put the mouse over a pic, the image change in all img in the page like the page in jsfiddle

Comment: @Davide this is because $(".lazy") get all images (is a class on more than one images). You need to get only the lazy where you are. In your handleMouseOver you can add this `$(this).find(".lazy")` to get the current over image. If you want I can post an example "collega italiano".

Comment: @erikscandola mi faresti un grande favore :)

Comment: I create an answer for you. I did changes for images and rects. You need to do the same with texts. Hope it helps :-) Note: you have to solve some bugs with timings and events queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kwnwj6q/4/) with an update of your code. I changed only a part, particularly:

```
$immagine = null;
$rect = null;
```

This two variables are initializated on mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture which element was mouse-over'ed then use something imilar to this: http://jsbin.com/udeha4/15/edit?html,css,js,output and call change image function on proper element.

Comment: Please add an example of your code directly to your answer.